# How can I start learning about objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ipad

I would like to start developing an application for Ipad (a simple one).

My doubt is that i heard that is only possible if you have a Mac, and isnt with a PC. Is it true?

Normally i use to develop applications using .Net and Visual Studio, how is the learning curve taking in count this fact?

Do you have any good web reference or tutorials about objective C?

Comment: Yep, if you want to build native applications for iOS, you need a Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad development without a mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949516/ipad-development-without-a-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,native Ipad development using XCode requires a Mac.. there is just no getting around that.

Objective C 's syntax is a little weirder than what you will be used to... lots of [] instead of .

but the concepts are going to be pretty much the same. If you have an Ipad, there are lots of free apple docs in the ibook store that you can go though. or if you have joined the developer program, then developer.apple.com has some amazing stuff with downloadable examples.

All the best

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you need a Mac. Objective-C isn't a very complicated language, so factor in maybe a day or two for getting used to Xcode and learning the language. Then it has so far taken me about ten years to get an incomplete understanding of the APIs...but only because there are things I didn't need to use yet :-).

Apple has very good documentation of Objective-C at its website, [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).